# Exclude S3 folders from bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix)

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I have a python boto3 code which lists all the objects under s3 folder/prefix. This code will return all the objects i.e.

temp/test/date=17-09-2019/

temp/test/date=17-09-2019/100.json

I want to exclude **temp/test/date=17-09-2019/** key from the response. I know that concept of folder does not exist in s3. Please find my code below:

```
bucket_name = 'temp-bucket'
prefix = 'temp/test/date=17-09-2019'

bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
s3_files = list(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix))

for file in s3_files:
    print(file)
```

Is there a way to exclude folder's from the response ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can check `item.size`, as directories has size=0:

```
for item in response:
    if item.size > 0:
        print(item.key)
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to filter out the results, but you can do this as follow:

```
import boto3

bucket_name = 'temp-bucket'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

ignore = s3.Bucket(bucket_name ).objects.filter(Prefix='temp/test/date=17-09-2019')
response = s3.Bucket(bucket_name ).objects.all()

for item in response:
    if item not in ignore:
        print(item.key)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate excluding a prefix by instead checking every prefix that does not match `'temp/test/date=17-09-2019'`:

```py
bucket_name = 'temp-bucket'
prefix = 'temp/test/date=17-09-2019'

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3_files = []

# construct a valid prefix by taking a part of the exclusion prefix
# and adding a character so that it would not match the exclusion prefix
for exclude_char in range(len(prefix)):
    # assume that object names are made of characters in the English alphabet + punctuation
    for printable in string.printable:
        if printable != prefix[exclude_char]:
            prefix = prefix[:exclude_char]+printable
            print(len(s3_files), 'files found, checking prefix', prefix)
            # AWS returns max 1000 objects, pagination is needed for more
            list_kwargs = dict(Bucket=bucket_name, MaxKeys=1000, Prefix=prefix)
            continuation_token = None
            while True:
                if continuation_token:
                    list_kwargs['ContinuationToken'] = continuation_token
                response = s3.list_objects_v2(**list_kwargs)
                s3_files.extend(response.get('Contents', []))
                if not response.get('IsTruncated'):
                    break
                continuation_token = response.get('NextContinuationToken')

for file in s3_files:
    print(file)
```

The code makes lots of `list_objects` calls, checking every conceivable prefix that does not match `'temp/test/date=17-09-2019'`. The prefixes it checks are created by taking increasingly long substrings of `'temp/test/date=17-09-2019'` and adding a character that does not come next in `'temp/test/date=17-09-2019'`.

The first substring it takes is the empty string `''`. It then tries every letter in the alphabet, creating N prefixes where N is the size of the alphabet. So it will try prefixes `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, etc. When it gets to the prefix `'t'`, it is skipped because it matches with the beginning of `'temp/test/date=17-09-2019'`.

Then a larger substring is taken: `'t'`. The code will construct prefixes `'ta'`, `'tb'`, `'tc'`, etc, and list objects with these prefixes, but it will skip prefix `'te'`.

If you find yourself needing this code snippet, you are likely querying lots of objects, so I also added pagination support here, because you can only list 1000 objects at a time from S3.

Beware the assumption I made about the alphabet. If your object names use other characters, then include those in the alphabet. However, try to keep the alphabet short to reduce the number of queries.

I needed this code to exclude hundreds of millions of objects. Listing those would have taken forever and would have been quite costly. If you need to exclude thousands of objects, it is faster and more fool proof to list all objects and filter them locally in your computer.

Optimization tip: If all the keys you wish to include also begin with `'temp/test/date='` then you can make the query a lot faster by replacing

```py
for exclude_char in range(len(prefix)):
```

with

```py
for exclude_char in range(len('temp/test/date='), len(prefix)):
```